# Jquery - Add character after the first character of a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say for example I have

```
var input = "C\\\\Program Files\\\\Need for Speed";

var output = do_it(input, ':');
```

Now, I would like output to have the value below :

```
 C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Need for Speed
```

I need to add a character to the given string just after the first character. How can I achieve that using javascript or jquery ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably not the most efficient way, but I would do something like:

(note: this is just pseudocode)

```
var output = input[0] + ":" + input.substr(1, input.length);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this like

```
String.prototype.addAt = function (index, character) {
        return this.substr(0, index - 1) + character + this.substr(index-1 + character.length-1);
    }
    var input = "C\\Program Files\\Need for Speed";
    var result = input.addAt(2, ':');
```

Answer (score 1):

Heres one way of doing it:

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/FjfB9/

```
var input = "C\\Program Files\\Need for Speed"

var do_it = function(str, char) {
    var str = str.split(''),
        temp = str.shift()

    str.unshift(temp, char)
    return str.join('')
}

console.log(do_it(input, ":"))
```